# Google ChromeDriver can't run in xvfb in EC2 server, errors out as soon as sendkeys() is called

Tags: amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver, xvfb, headless-browser

I am getting following error when I try to run my selenium code to launch chrome driver and test signin functionality in EC2 Box.

I run Xvfb server like this, in another terminal `Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1366x768x24 -ac`.

I have also added `export DISPLAY=:1` to `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable`

Basicaly I am trying to test signin functionality on this link: https://talentconnect.pge.com/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/hrrcf_a_startpage_ext_cand?sap-wd-configId=ZPERJ_STARTPAGE_EXT_CAND&sap-client=810

And as soon as code hits `sendkey()` call for login credential it gives this error.

Error Log:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: an X display is required for keycode conversions, consider using Xvfb
(Session info: chrome=31.0.1650.63)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.8.240825,platform=Linux 3.2.0-36-virtual x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 83 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.33.0', revision: '4ecaf82108b2a6cc6f006aae81961236eba93358', time: '2013-05-22 12:00:17'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-36-virtual', java.version: '1.7.0_25'
Session ID: 9e7150582926e064d5c93c97a87b9008
```

Answer (score -1):

Update both Selenium and ChromeDriver: [docs.seleniumhq.org/download](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) and [chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html). Right version is primarily necessary.